# Arduino error in code Stack smashing protect failure!

Tags: arduino-uno, c, esp32

I get the error when I compiled my code below. I am making an application to read temperature on board ttgo esp32 oled lora

```
stack smashing protect failure!

abort() was called at PC 0x400da3e8 on core 1

Backtrace: 0x4008b8f4:0x3ffb1ec0 0x4008bb21:0x3ffb1ee0 0x400da3e8:0x3ffb1f00 0x400d0f69:0x3ffb1f20 0x400d0f73:0x3ffb1f50 0x400d366e:0x3ffb1f70 0x400d12f7:0x3ffb1f90 0x400d68a9:0x3ffb1fb0 0x40087a71:0x3ffb1fd0

Rebooting...
ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57

rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 188777542, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fff0018,len:4
load:0x3fff001c,len:1100
load:0x40078000,len:9344
load:0x40080400,len:6348
entry 0x400806a8
Node v0.2
Trigger Temps
Read Temps = 25.50
Read Temps = 25.50
Send Temp: 25.50
Packet queued
238190: EV_TXCOMPLETE (includes waiting for RX windows)
```

Code is in => https://github.com/Mangulomx/ds18b20_lora1/blob/master/ds18b20_1_lora.ino

Comment: why are you using the `arduino-uno` tag?

Comment: `when I compiled my code below` - a) there is no code below, and b) that doesn't look like a compilation error, more like a runtime error